# Removing Foundation 6 Dropdown Arrows

Tags: html, css, navigation, zurb-foundation

I have been unable to remove the dropdown arrow on my menu using any method I have found online. Here is the menu, I am not very versed in Foundation, so I suspect I have the menu wrong. A draft can be found [here](http://c0092.paas1.tx.modxcloud.com/stack/ties_foundation.html). Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
<div class="row show-for-medium">

<div class="column large-12">
    <div class="title-bar-left">
        <img src="assets/img/ties_logo_header.jpg" class="site-logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar-right" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-show-for="medium"></div>       

      <div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
        <ul class="dropdown menu align-right" data-responsive-menu="medium-accordion">
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a class="menu-item" href="#">Our Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News &amp; Resources</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu is-dropdown-submenu-parent" style="position:absolute;z-index:10;">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
            </ul>                 
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

The only css fix I can find, but hasn't worked:

```
  .dropdown.menu .is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow > a::after {
    content: none !important; }

  .dropdown.menu .is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-left-arrow > a::after {
    content: none !important; }

  .dropdown.menu .is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-right-arrow > a::after {
    content: none !important; }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**please try below css:**

```
<style>
.is-accordion-submenu-parent[aria-expanded="true"] > a::after{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I had to also add:
.is-accordion-submenu-parent[aria-expanded="false"] > a::after{
  display: none;

Answer (score 0):

```
.is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a:after {
    display:none!important;
}
```